# Interesting Contract Creation Transaction

Tags: transactions, contract-deployment

I am TOTALLY new to all of this, but slowly trying to learn the basics of contract creation. I've been going through on Etherscan and looking at contract creation transactions to understand them a bit better.

Well, I came across this one the other day (I've masked out any info that personalizes the trans action):

[image]

The "Vb" in the TOKENS TRANSFERRED line is Vitalik (Bueterin) as I understand it.

But what role did he play (if any) in this contract deployment?

Just trying to understand what all the info means and thought this was a unique example!

Thank you!!!

Comment: Why u removed the tx hash from the picture! It all public anyway.

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to this and just getting to know how this all works. I didn't want to call attention to the particular contract, just try to understand the information I was seeing.

Comment: Don’t worry  there are bots and services around the globe watching the transactions of VB. So post the tx hash so we can see it directly in ethescan and maybe under ur question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what role did he play (if any) in this contract deployment?

He didn't.

Just like [all the other token deployments featuring his address](https://etherscan.io/tokentxns?a=0xab5801a7d398351b8be11c439e05c5b3259aec9b).

(I'm assuming this is for the token named `SPAGINU&#127837`, which I worked out from the timestamp.)

Looking at the constructor of the contract:

```
constructor (address payable FeeAddress, address payable marketingWalletAddress) {
        _FeeAddress = FeeAddress;
        _marketingWalletAddress = marketingWalletAddress;
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[FeeAddress] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[marketingWalletAddress] = true;
        emit Transfer(address(0xAb5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }
```

All it's doing is emitting an event with Vitalik's address hard-coded as the sender.

Now that Etherscan has implemented its Labels feature - which allows Vitalik to be labelled as `Vb` - this is presumably a good way to advertise a new coin, on the assumption that lots of people like watching Vitalik's address, and may in some way associate him (as you did) with a token that's unlikely to be a good investment... :-)

Comment: AH! That makes total sense! A great explanation. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond!!

Comment: No problem - happy to help :-)

Comment: Yes, I believe this token was a known scam I discovered from Token Sniffer, but I hadn't seen that type of line before. Now that I've been looking, I've seen seen similar "emits" in various contracts I've been exploring. For example, one contract had the same line but instead of VB's address, it was 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000. Is the only purpose of such an "emit event" to deceive? And what would be the purpose of using 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000? Sorry for all the questions. I've taken up too much of your time already. Very grateful for all the help!

Comment: No worries :-) Okay, in the case of using `0x0...` - this is a sort of de facto way of saying new tokens are being minted or created (or burned). There's nothing in any of the specifications to say to do this, but lots of people do, as it allows the events to be indexed by block explorers. So in this case it's all above board, and no deception is intended. There are a few previous questions on the topic, like this one -> https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28087/why-transfer0x0-to-amount-after-minting-tokens

Comment: (I realise we're talking about contract creations here, rather than a function call to something like `mint()`, but it's along the same lines: "I'm sending some new tokens to an address.")

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you SO much for your reply. You are very kind to take the time. Really!!!

Thanks for the great explanations and people like you are what make this site great!!!!!!